# Create a script to safely add entries to the /etc/hosts file

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to create a script which safely adds entries to etc/host however I dont know how to start question.
There are various entries however it doesn't state what kind of entires so can anyone help me with the question please

Answer (score 0):

The question not clear, however to give you a starting point you can find a good script here
https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/a7b0a079e7727a4315b9
[image: Image from the same source]